# Custom Options in magento

Tags: magento, custom-attributes

How to pass the price values to add to cart instead of passing Title in `magento` application. I want to show only price in checkout pages insteadOf Product title. So can you tell me how to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
your_theme\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml
```

override this file and comment product name,qty  etc.